# Search Product by name in magento and get array of product ids

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to search product of a particular store in `magento` and want to get all `product ids` in the array programmatically. like the below method which takes `$searchstring` as parameter and `return $ids` array which has product ids of all those products where the name of product has contain the `search string`.

```
function getProductIdsBySearch($searchstring, $storeId) {
     $ids = array();
     //
     // Code to Search Product by $searchstring and get Product IDs
     //
     return $ids;
}
```

Like :-
If we have following Products on Catalog

```
ID      Product Name  
1        Temp   
2        ProductTemp   
3        ProductTempData  
4        ABCTEMPXYZ  
5        ABCXYZ  
6        Tempdata
```

and search string is **temp** then it should return 1,2,3,4,6 not 5 because **temp** not matched with name of product which has `id = 5`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always use filter query with 'like'.

Give it a try...

```
function getProductIdsBySearch($searchstring, $storeId = '') {
     $ids = array();     

     // Code to Search Product by $searchstring and get Product IDs
     $product_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$searchstring.'%'))
                  ->load();

     foreach ($product_collection as $product) {
         $ids[] = $product->getId();
     }
    //return array of product ids
    return $ids;
}
```